# Using React Router with Multiple URL Segments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a React App using React Router. I have a `/inventory` page and another at `/inventory/edit`. Here's the Switch I set up for all my pages:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
      <Route exact path='/store' component={Store}/>
      <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
      <Route exact path='/admin' component={Admin}/>
      <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
      <Route exact path='/register' component={Register}/>
      <Route exact path='/inventory' component={Inventory}/>
      <Route exact path='/inventory/edit' component={EditItem}/>
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I can navigate to the `edit` page using a Link (`<Link to={{pathname: '/inventory/edit'}}>`) but if I type the URL into the browser address bar nothing is rendered and I'm left with a blank page. I noticed that in the browser console I get an error saying:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <                    bundle.js:1

So I'm not sure if its a problem with using Webpack or if its unrelated to that. I've also noticed that this happens with anything manually typed into the address bar that has more than one slash, so while `/store` works, `/store/test` will also show up blank. I want `/inventory/edit` to bring me to the correct page, but `/store/test` should bring me to my 404 page.

I've searched around but haven't found anything like this online. If anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong here that'd be great.

**EDIT (Solution)**

I had to change all the paths defined in my index.html file from `./foo/bar` to `/foo/bar`, which I figured out from Garry Taylor's comment.

Comment: This might be an issue loading resources? for example /bundle.js is now turned into /inventory/edit/bundle.js. Check you're network and make sure all the JS files are loading the content you expect. I bet the bundle.js is really the index.html default content from your server.

Comment: Ah! You were right! I just had to change all the paths in my index.html file from "./foo/bar" to "/foo/bar". Had no idea what was causing this before, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions:

### Webpack File

From here: [React Router not working when URL contains multiple paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54786191/react-router-not-working-when-url-contains-multiple-paths)
In your webpack config file, add an output configuration and set the publicPath to /. i.e

```
output:{
  publicPath: '/'
}
```

For completion sake, you can also add the publicPath in the devServer config if you have one (optional). i.e

```
devServer:{
  ...
  publicPath:'/'
}
```

### Index.html

Adding the HTML base tag to the header section of your index.html file should provide the same result. i.e

```html
<base href="/">
```