# React Router not working when URL contains multiple paths

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I'm using the **webpack-dev-server** for development and equally react router. This is my wepack configuration.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const common = require('./common.config.js')
const merge  = require('webpack-merge')

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    mode:'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
           {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
            use: [
                       {
                  // Adds CSS to the DOM by injecting a `<style>` tag
                  loader: 'style-loader'
                       },
                       {
                          // Interprets `@import` and `url()` like `import/require()` and will resolve them
                          loader: 'css-loader'
                   },
                   {
                          // Loader for webpack to process CSS with PostCSS
                          loader: 'postcss-loader',
                          options: {
                          plugins: function () {
                                return [
                                require('autoprefixer')
                                ];
                                   }
                          }
                       },
               {
                  // Loads a SASS/SCSS file and compiles it to CSS
                  loader: 'sass-loader'
               }
                 ]
           }
        ]
    },
    devServer:{
       contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
       port: 3000,
       proxy:{
          '/api': 'http://127.0.0.1:5000',
       },
       historyApiFallback:true,
       overlay: true,
       stats: 'normal'
    },
    watchOptions: {
       ignored: /node_modules/
    },

    plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['../dist'], { exclude:['sw.js']}),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Script App - Dev',
            filename: '../dist/index.html',
        template:'index_template.html'
        }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'bundled_styles.css'
        }),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()    
    ],
});
```

here is the entry point to my app (where I've defined the routes)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'

import configureStore from './store/configureStore';

import FirstComponent from './FirstComponent';
import SecondComponent from './SecondComponent';
import App from './App';

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App>
               <Switch>
                   <Route path="/first/:a_code" component={FirstComponent} />
                   <Route path="/second" component={SecondComponent} />
               </Switch>
            </App>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,

    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I'm using `react-router` `v4` and `wepack` `v4.29`.

**My problem:** When I push routes from my code using the `history` prop, everything works well but when I refresh my browser with the route, Everything goes blank. **This behavior is observed only with the route that has multiple paths**(`/first/:param`).

**What I've tried**: I read from some SO posts that I had to set the `historyApiFallback` property in my webpack config to `true`, and I did but it still did not help.
One of the comments in [this github issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/676) says that `historyApiFallback` will not work well if certain `proxy` configurations are available in the webpack config.

I don't want to remove these `proxy` configurations because I'm making api calls to another server running on a different port.

Can anyone help me on this? Please!

Comment: Can you provide an example of how the route looks in the address bar?

Comment: @RRK here is an example of the route: http://localhost:3000/first/rt

Comment: Just a hunch, can  you try parameter name without an underscore? eg `:a_code` to `:acode`

Comment: @RRK I doubt if that's where the problem is because, I used a different variable name without the underscore earlier but it did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually missed a webpack configuration. I had to add an `output` configuration and set the `publicPath` to `/`. i.e

```
output:{
  publicPath: '/'
}
```

I also added the `publicPath` in the `devServer` config. i.e

```
devServer:{
  ...
  publicPath:'/',
  historyApiFallback: true
}
```

---

**Update:**

Equally make sure that your `bundle.js` script is inserted in your html file like this:

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

**AND NOT**

`<script src="./bundle.js"></script>` OR `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: This is what worked for me. Also for future folks, in modern HTML5 supported browsers, assuming you dont have access to the webpack config file, or you only support modern browsers, adding `<base href="/">` to the header section of your index.html file also works

Comment: the publicPath in devServer{} made no difference for me, but the bundle.js reference in my html file completely solved the problem.  works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, and I solved using the render: func, that avoids the component to be remounted when the location matches.

So my route look´s like this

```
<Route
  path="/first/:a_code"
  render={props => 
    <FirstComponent {...props}/>
  }
/>
```

and then in my component I get the params with match

```
const first_component = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.match.params.a_code}
    </div>
  )
}
```

at the url "/first/something" I can refresh the browser and still get the desired params, and without any error or blank page. And I don´t believe is a config issue because I didn´t eject the webpack configs in this project so far.